# django gives duplicate error everytime the project runs

Tags: mysql, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views

I am trying to add some data which is in response_body to my 'Offenses' table in my database 'dashboard'

I want to add this data only once,so at the first time the data was added to my database successfully  but after that it gave me this error because it obviously refuse to create duplicate entry for another oid which is set as unique

How can I modify my code so that the data is added only once and no duplicate data is added and it does not give me this error `django.db.utils.IntegrityError: (1062, "Duplicate entry '4767' for key 'PRIMARY'")`

Below is my code.
I have created the table from models.py and adding the data from views.py because the data is present in views.py and it was easier to add the data from here.

if there is any other suitable approach please suggest.

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import UserManager
from django.core.validators import int_list_validator
# Create your models here.

class Offenses(models.Model):
    oid = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    description = models.CharField(null=False, max_length=20)
    assigned_to = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=20)
    categories = models.TextField(null=True)
    category_count = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    policy_category_count = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    security_category_count = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    close_time = models.TimeField(null=True)
    closing_user = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    closing_reason_id = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    credibility = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    relevance = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    severity = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    magnitude = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    destination_networks = models.TextField(null=True)
    source_network = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=20)
    device_count = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    event_count = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    flow_count = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    inactive = models.BooleanField(null=True)
    last_updated_time = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    local_destination_count = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    offense_source = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    offense_type = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    protected = models.BooleanField(null=True)
    follow_up = models.BooleanField(null=True)
    remote_destination_count = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    source_count = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    start_time = models.TimeField(null=True)
    status = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=20)
    username_count = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    source_address_ids = models.TextField(null=True)
    local_destination_address_ids = models.TextField(null=True)
    domain_id = models.IntegerField(null=True)

    objects = UserManager()
    class Meta:
        db_table = "offenses"
```

views.py

```
response_body = json.loads(response.read().decode('utf-8'))


    for j in response_body:
        obj = Offenses.objects.create(oid=j['id'], description=j['description'])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Django's [get_or_create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create):

```
obj, created = Offenses.objects.get_or_create(oid=j['id'], defaults={'description': j['description']})
```

Comment: it shows a key_error if i am adding another field to save it.

Comment: `response_body = json.loads(response.read().decode('utf-8'))

    for j in response_body:
        obj, created = Offenses.objects.get_or_create(oid=j['id'], defaults={'description': j['description'], 'assigned_to': j['assigned_to'], 'magnitude': j['magnitude']})`   --- so the magnitude is int type in the database and should return a number.

Comment: That looks like an error which is not related to this question. Consider open up a new thread. Are you sure that j['magnitude'] is always defined?